# Line Integral in Complex field

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

I am trying to compute

$\displaystyle\oint_{|z| = 1/2} \dfrac{z^2+1}{3z^3+z^2} \, dz$ in the positive orientation

I get $14 \pi i $ by the residue theorem, but in my text the answer is $\displaystyle{2\pi i\over 3}$.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Consider posting your work in the post so that others might proofread and provide constructive feedback. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Did you note that there is a pole at $z=-1/3$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you got $14\pi i$. If you show your work, we might be able to spot the error.

Here is one way to get the answer. Using partial fractions, $\dfrac{z^2+1}{3z^3+z^2} = \dfrac{-3}{z}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{\tfrac{10}{3}}{z+\tfrac{1}{3}}$. Hence, 
\begin{align*}\oint_{|z| = 1/2}\dfrac{z^2+1}{3z^3+z^2}\,dz & = \oint_{|z| = 1/2}\left(\dfrac{-3}{z}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{\tfrac{10}{3}}{z+\tfrac{1}{3}}\right)\,dz \\ &= \oint_{|z| = 1/2}\dfrac{-3}{z}\,dz + \oint_{|z| = 1/2}\dfrac{1}{z^2}\,dz + \oint_{|z| = 1/2}\dfrac{\tfrac{10}{3}}{z+\tfrac{1}{3}}\,dz \\ &= -3 \cdot 2\pi i + 0 + \dfrac{10}{3} \cdot 2\pi i \\ &= \dfrac{2\pi i}{3}.\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for confirm the answer, i finally find the error,